# Database sync between local and production

Tags: database, content, deployment

I was watching Mark Jaquith's presentation at WCSF 2013 recently and in the Q&A Mark mentioned something about rsync - after a quick Google I can see this is done via SSH - my question is this: is this something that can be done to a local development environment? Do you still need to copy the database and change configuration, url references etc? For a local setup should I just stick to using a script to change the references?

Answer (score 3):

If you have databases reachable from the outside ie: mysql1.example.com you can work on a local development environment connected to that the whole time.

I just found a nice thing to put in wp-config.php to be able to change the host depending on your environment

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $host );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $host );
```

Then there are setups like:

- Varying Vagrant: https://github.com/10up/varying-vagrant-vagrants
- WP-Stack: https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-Stack

Comment: How do I find out if the database is reachable outside? Is this the same as remote access?

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting?

Comment: I use both shared and VPS

Comment: Okey, for shared hosting it depends if they have mysql on other servers, you can see in your wp-config.php if it points to localhost or some other server. You can setup remote access as you wrote before on your VPS, like this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html and add your public ip from where you are working so its secure. Another way can be to add vpn-tunnle to the server.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out. For VPS it looks pretty simple but I guess it's a little more difficult for shared - all my shared are pointing to localhost

Comment: hey @PontusAbrahamsson - just to clarify something for a new user (me) - for your "define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $host );" to work do you have to alter the database to say (presumably) 'WP_HOME' in all the relevant places?